# c#:how to find switched on computers in domain c#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

i want to get list of Switched on computers in domain.  curently i can get list of computers in domain by using `directoryentry class` but it gives list of all computers in domain whether it is switched on or not. i already reffered 2,3 links on stackoverflow but didnt get answer. `pinging` takes  more time. Is there any efficient solution for this in c# ?

Comment: pinging might be the only solution

Comment: What do you need this information for? Maybe there's a better way to solve whatever the motivating problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at a solution like SCOM for this. It provides a "Heartbeat" functionality which is more reliable than ping (some corporate firewalls might block icmp, e.g. ping traffic). And a bunch of other monitoring stuff. It does mean more management overhead though.

If you want the simplest solution you can't get around ping. Maybe you can use a multithreaded ping like here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1202/c-multi-thread-ping

Answer (score 0):

To solve this i simply made a C# app that does a ping to all computers, this can be done very quickly depending on your network.

Basicly what you do is (And what i did):
1) Fetch you network guy
2) Talk to him, ask him if has any "flood protection".
3) If he is not screaming, spawn as many threads as you can and use them ping the machines :).

@Mr Happy already link to code on how to multi thread ping ( Not that its a issue at all).